# Adding special characters while writing into a java file but not visible everywhere

Tags: java, special-characters

I am writing into a java file through

```
               FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("someFile.java");
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                out.write(strContents);
                // Close the output stream
                out.close();
```

but after writing I found it appended some special characters in shape of box like [], but those special characters are only visible in specific text editor like EditPlus.

How to avoid those special characters while writing or is it specific to some editors only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice would be to avoid using `FileWriter` completely. It *always* uses the platform default encoding, which is rarely a good idea.

I would suggest using `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter` - then you just need to specify an appropriate encoding, such as UTF-8. Obviously you'll still need to use an editor which supports UTF-8, and you *may* need to tell it the encoding... but at least you'll have code which *always* writes in the same way, regardless of OS and system properties.

Answer (score 0):

Normal notepad application can't show the special character wriiten in the file. There is no any problem with your code. It is limitation of notepad.

Comment: The point mentioned by you is correct , just wanted to know, was I doing something wrong.

Comment: As per Jon Skeet, you should FileOutputStream instead of FileWritter. But it will gives you same result. So you are not doing wrong.